# android app crashing after adding navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer

i am working on this android app.In this app, the "StartingActivity.java" is automatically getting changed to "HomeActivity.java" which contains the Navigation Drawer. But while changing the activity,the app crashes.Please help..
Here is the code

StartingActivity.java

```
 package com.example.abhi.mymanager;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class StartingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);
  // for sending it to another activity after a time
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Intent i=new Intent(StartingActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
          }
        }
    },5000);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_starting, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

HomeActivity.java

```
package com.example.abhi.mymanager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 /**
 * Created by abhi on 29-01-2015.
 */
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,options));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this,options[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(options[position]);
    }
}
```

activity_starting.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  tools:context=".StartingActivity"
    android:background="#ffb6a6ff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="My Manager"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff2312ff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

home_layout.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- the main content view-->
        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- the navigation drawer-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:entries="@array/Options"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"

        />
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abhi.mymanager" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My Manager</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="Options">
        <item name="MyBoard">My Board</item>
        <item name="CreateBoard">Create Board</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

logcat

```
02-01 17:23:55.811  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕      Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:23:56.171  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11346: Landroid/view /ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11352: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11354: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9040: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11349: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 365: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-01 17:23:56.181  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 17:23:56.191  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-01 17:23:56.191  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-01 17:23:56.191  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 17:23:58.851  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:23:59.561  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:23:59.911  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/PGA﹕ New SOCKET connection: .abhi.mymanager (pid 13075, tid 13075)
02-01 17:24:00.081  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:24:01.661  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-01 17:24:01.661  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2c9e180)
02-01 17:24:01.661  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ procName from cmdline: com.example.abhi.mymanager
02-01 17:24:01.661  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName  :com.example.abhi.mymanager
02-01 17:24:01.671  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ file written successfully with content: com.example.abhi.mymanager StringBuffer : ;com.example.abhi.mymanager
02-01 17:24:01.681  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:24:02.081  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:24:02.531  13075-13082/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-01 17:24:03.021  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13075 SIG: 9
02-01 17:24:03.021  13075-13075/com.example.abhi.mymanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abhi.mymanager/com.example.abhi.mymanager.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at             android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:154)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
        at com.example.abhi.mymanager.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the logcat.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace :)

Comment: logcat is not complete. missing some (may) the most important part :) where it says `caused by`

Comment: "Caused by" is added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `options` array is not initialized. You cannot pass a `null` as the array to `ArrayAdapter`.